# How do I get my code to read all lines of a text file?

Tags: python

I'm going to try to explain this. I am a beginner (so please, no difficult terminology lol) working on a code where users in a library borrow books. Each user has a library code and a number of credits to use. The details of these are in a text file. The first column is the library numbers. The second column is their credit balance. The third column is the minimum credit amount. The fourth column is the maximum credit amount:

```
ABC, 125, 150, 200
ABD, 80, 30, 80
ABE, 0, 23, 50
ABF, 20, 20, 50
ABG, 78, 30, 80
ABH, 92, 90, 300
ABI, 3, 9, 20
ABJ, 7, 6, 38
```

When their balance reaches their minimum credit balance, more credits need to be added. I would like for my program to read the text file and identify which users need to have more credits added to their account in order to exceed the minimum credit balance. I would also like to specify how many more credits they would need to reach the maximum credit balance. I would like for these details to be written in a separate file. Here is what i've done so far:

```
f = open("customerInfo.txt", "r")
for line in f.readlines():
z = line.split(", ")
UserID = z[0]
CreditBalance = z[1]
MinBalance = z[2]
MaxBalance = z[3]
HowManyAwayFromMaxBalance = MaxBalance - CreditBalance

if int(z[2]) - int(z[1] <= 0:
    CreditInfo = open("creditinfo.txt", "w") #This is a blank text file
    CreditInfo.write("User", UserID, "needs more credits. In order to reach the maximum credit balance, they would need", HowManyAwayFromMaxBalance, "credits added to their account./n"
```

This does not work for every single line. How would I edit this code so that it read every single line and did the same thing for each line by itself? Because hundreds of names will be added to this list, so I would like for it to happen automatically. So, in this case, details for adding credits to accounts ABC, ABE, ABF and ABI would be printed in the creditinfo.txt file automatically. Thank you in advance and please ask if this is confusing.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation so we can see how that `for` loop works?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mistakes in the code you posted and I am not yet clear what exactly you problem is. If you can explain that, please let me know.

**This worked fine for me:**

```
f = open("customerInfo.txt", "r")
fw = open("creditInfo.txt", "w")

for line in f.readlines():
        z = line.split(", ")
        UserID = z[0]
        CreditBalance = int(z[1])
        MinBalance = int(z[2])
        MaxBalance = int(z[3])
        HowManyAwayFromMaxBalance = MaxBalance - CreditBalance

        if (MinBalance - CreditBalance) <= 0:
            fw.write("User " + UserID + " needs more credits. In order to reach the maximum credit balance, they would need " + str(HowManyAwayFromMaxBalance) + " credits added to their account.\n")

f.close()
fw.close()
```